# Webrtc app only works when firewall is disabled

Tags: webrtc, centos7, firewall

I have a video conference app build using webrtc.
**I also have TURN server functioning well. (I am using coturn)**

I have opened all ports required by the app on firewall. [Openvidu deployment instruction](http://openvidu.io/docs/deployment/deploying-ubuntu/)

**But my app only works when I disable firewall.**

Now what I want to do is find what is being blocked by firewall so that my app doesnt work.

I am really stuck.

Is there any way to find what is being blocked by firewall preventing my app to function well.

I am using `CentOS 7`. And `firewalld` for managing firewall.

Answer (score 2):

Check what type of ICE candidates your client gathers (see [here](https://testrtc.com/webrtc-api-trace/) for some hints how).

If the firewall blocks UDP and you only have a udp turn server configured that is not going to work. And there will be situations where no connection can be established so your app should provide a user experience for that as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the candidates being returned using [this](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/).  You will need to add the location of your server into STUN or TURN URI field.  Check the differences in the returned candidates with your firewall off and on.  Most of the issues that I have seen are around open ports on firewalls.  CoTURN defaults to 3478 & 5349.

Generally setting your turnserver to listen on port 443 helps if you don't want to open more ports on your firewall, however I'm guessing that there will be some configuration changes inside of openvidu (I'm not that au fait with that implementation)